# supporting the texture format GL_RGB_422_APPLE (8 bits per pixel) in Opengl es 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, irrlicht

i have been trying to add support for GL_RGB_422_APPLE.

internalFormat = GL_RGB;

pixelFormat = GL_RGB_422_APPLE;

PixelType = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_APPLE;

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, InternalFormat, 2048, 2048, 0, PixelFormat, PixelType, 0);
```

But `glCheckFramebufferStatus` is returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT error.

it is working well for following formats : internalFormat = GL_RGB;

pixelFormat = GL_RGB;

PixelType = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;

is there any other steps to do to support GL_RGB_422_APPLE ?

In our project we are using a texture that just stores bool values(0/1) for every pixel. For storing a bool values 16bits/pixel is so costlier.that is why i'm looking for above implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, as a mere OpenGL developer, cannot "add support" for anything. That's the job of an implementor. With OpenGL ES (GLES) 2.0, unless supported by an extension, you simply cannot use `RGB_422_APPLE` for framebuffer attachments. Actually, the GLES 2.0 spec doesn't even mention any *sized internal formats*. Oddly enough, they *do* use sized internal formats for the description of when framebuffer attachments are legal and don't compromise framebuffer completeness.

Anyway, even if you did have support for regular textures and `RGBA_422_APPLE` via the appropriate extension, that doesn't say anything about if and how the [sized internal] format is legal for use as a framebuffer attachment and from skimming the [extension spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/APPLE/rgb_422.txt) of said format, there is no indication that it is legal.

I guess you're out of luck in this particular case.

**EDIT:** To clarify, to be able to use a non-depth/non-stencil texture as a framebuffer attachment, it *must* be *color-renderable*. The above mentioned spec doesn't mention anything on that matter and the implementation you're using seems to think so as well.

Comment: ya i can't add support. opengl es 2.0 would also support 8 bits/pixel textures(RGBA_422_APPLE). Also i found that only few internal formats that are colored-renderable are accepted by glTexImage2D. is there a way to reduce textures memory size in gpu ?

Comment: The spec only mentions 16-bit RGB(A) formats. Either RGBA4, RGB5_A1 or RGB565. I'm a desktop GL guy but I'm still gonna say: no. Incidentally, what are your requirements? Also, GLES 3.0 supports formats lik R8 which you *could* use to encode something like an 2-4-2 RGB value or something but even then, 8 bits is as low as it gets.